# How to include images in xhtml2pdf generated pdf files?

Tags: templates, jinja2, xhtml2pdf

I am running a streamlit app which generates reports containing images and dataframes. I have used `jinja2` to generate the html file from a template. Then, I would now like to convert to a pdf file using `xhtml2pdf` to download.

How to do that?

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader


def convert_html_to_pdf(source_html, output_filename="temp/report.pdf"):

    result_file = io.BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        source_html,                
        dest=result_file)
    return pdf.getvalue()


def load_template():
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
    template = env.get_template('catAnalysisTemplate.html')
    return template


def render_report(data, filename="report"):
    template = load_template()
    html = template.render(data)
    # with open(f'temp/{filename}.html', 'w') as f:
    #     f.write(html)
    pdf = convert_html_to_pdf(html)

    return [html, pdf]
```

This works fine except the images are not included in the pdf file. My static images are stored in

```
img/
   logo.png
```

and the charts I may generate it in memory as like

```
def plot_co_attainment(qp):
    img = io.BytesIO()
    data = qp.co_attainment()[["Level", "Perc_Attainment"]]
    plt.figure(dpi=150)
    plt.bar(data["Level"], data["Perc_Attainment"], width=0.5, color=colors)
    for i, val in enumerate(data["Perc_Attainment"].values):
        plt.text(i, val, str(val) + "%",
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='bottom',
                 fontdict={'fontweight': 500, 'size': 20})
    plt.xlabel("Course Outcomes")
    plt.ylabel("Percentage of Attainment")
    plt.ylim((0, 110))
    plt.savefig(buf, format='jpg')
    return buf
```

How do I connect the dots and get the images in my pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.  The way I solved it was to use a `link_handler` and return the data as a `data:` uri containing the png image data.

This example will take the `src` attribute and use it to generate a square image in that color, which will be embedded in the PDF.  Sadly this doesn't let you modify the image tag *itself* so you can't change the sizes/classes or anything else.

Using something like this opens the way to embedding just about anything without having to add them to your template directly.

```
from base64 import b64encode
from io import BytesIO

from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from PIL import Image

html_src = """
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="red"/>
        <img src="green"/>
        <img src="blue"/>
    </div>
</body>
"""


def link_callback(src_attr, *args):
    """
    Returns the image data for use by the pdf renderer
    """
    img_out = BytesIO()
    img = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100), src_attr)
    img.save(img_out, "png")
    return f"data:image/png;base64,{b64encode(img_out.getvalue())}"


def main():
    with open("one.pdf", "wb") as f:
        pizza = pisa.CreatePDF(
            html_src,
            dest=f,
            link_callback=link_callback,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: After all this I gave up on `xhtml2pdf` and moved to `weasyprint`.  It works much better, but you do have wrangle some system level dependencies.  Basing docker images on `python:X.XX-slim-bullseye` rather than `buster` solved most of them.